# How can i isolate text-user in a web page?

Tags: php, html, css

i'll like to print in a web page,  text-user input, but it could have HTML-TAGs. However, if user makes wrong HTML or applies some CSS rule (e.g using style tag), i want that page content doesn't to be affected. (i don't like to use iframes).

Tags-user must be applied. I need to prevent bad-close-tag or errors or  global css rules, in the possible isolate javascript. A kind of "sandbox" by text-user.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use:

```
strip_tags($html,"<p><img>");    // only <p>,<img> is allowed
```

the javascript / style wont be executed,
but this doesnt get rid of the tag's body.

Answer (score 0):

You should use some pre-built filter for this, as there is no simple solution.

I recommend looking at [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), this will help you achieve the sandbox effect you're after.

`striptags` could be used but I don't recommend this as malicious code could be put inside the allowed tags.

Comment: I think he want a function to allow only particular html tag